# What is gradient with respect to components of a position vector?

Tags: classical-mechanics, vector-fields

[image]I am reading "Classical mechanics" by Goldstein, Poole and Safko, Third edition.
Kindly please refer to page no 10, last paragraph.

They write

> the subscript $i$ on the del operator indicates that derivatives are with respect to components of $\mathbf{r}_i$, ($\mathbf{r}_i$ is a position vector).

I only know one definition of the gradient operator and that is
$$\mathbf{i}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\mathbf{j}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}+\mathbf{k}\frac{\partial}{\partial z}.$$
 When applied to a scalar function, it calculates the slope of the scalar with respect to the $x$, $y$ and $z$ axes respectively these slopes produce the gradient of the scalar function used.

I have never seen the gradient with respect to a position vector. What is this? What is the recipe to calculate it? What does it physically signify?

Comment: Could you write your gradient expressions in MathJax? I believe I can answer this question, but I’m unsure of exactly what your expression/definition of the gradient is.

Comment: As far as I remember, Goldstein uses the notation $\nabla_i$ to denote the gradient with respect to the position-vector of the $i$th particle--not with respect to the $i$th component of any position-vector. Extra Point: Nonetheless, whenever it is clear from the context that $\nabla_i$ is supposed to mean gradient with respect to the $i$th component of a position-vector (unlike the case in Goldstein), it simply means the $i$th component of the full gradient with respect to the full position-vector (i.e., simply $\partial_i$).

Comment: I have uploaded the paragraph. It says "derivatives wrt components of ri"

Comment: Yes, exactly! Derivatives with respect to the components of $\vec{r}_i$ means the full gradient with respect to $\vec{r}_i$. It is different from the derivative with respect to the $i$th component of $\vec{r}$. In particular, here, $\vec{r}_i$ is the full position vector of the $i$th particle and the gradient $\nabla_i$ is the full gradient with respect to this full position vector of the $i$th particle. Try to realize how it is different from the derivative, say, $\partial_x$, which is a derivative with respect to a component of the full position vector of some particle. Does this make sense?

Comment: What is the recipe to calculate that?

Comment: It is just the usual gradient with respect to a position-vector. There is no special recipe to calculate it. The label $i$ just denotes the name of the specific position-vector with respect to which we are calculating the gradient. There is some potential for more dire confusion about the next bit of notation that Goldstein will use (on the next page :P) which is the symbol $\nabla_{ij}$. For that, I direct you to this existing post on PSE: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/74752/notation-of-nabla-ijv-ij-referring-to-a-potential?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

We have that $V_i$ depends on the position of one particle (the $i$-th particle). In general we could have a potential $V$ that depends on the positions of $N$ particles, so $V=V(\mathbf r_1,...,\mathbf r_N)$. Let's write this out fully for $N=2$:
$$V=V(x_1,y_1,z_1,x_2,y_2,z_2).$$
Then $\nabla_1V$ means
$$\left(\mathbf i\frac \partial{\partial x_1}+\mathbf j\frac \partial{\partial y_1}+\mathbf k\frac \partial{\partial z_1}\right)V(x_1,y_1,z_1,x_2,y_2,z_2)$$
and similarly you get $\nabla_iV$ by taking the derivative to the coordinates of the $i$'th particle.

Answer (score 0):

I think, he meant instead of  using (x,y,z) in the del- respectively $\nabla$-operator, the author uses $\mathbf{r_i}=(x_i,y_i,z_i)$, i.e. the components of $\mathbf{r}_i$.